# read data from multiple table into single topic

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to read data from multiple table into single topic in jdbc connector?

I have read certain articles about the same and found that it can be done using ksql db or data stream but couldn't got the clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
table.whitelist
    List of tables to include in copying
```

All of these tables will be sent to a topic.

Then you can use `RegexRouter` transform to modify the destination topic-name to a single value.